# Circuit design - usage of BOOT0 and a Hall effect sensor on STM32G431CBT6

Tags: motor-controller

I am working on motor project with STM32G431xxx, with their stock B-431B-ESC1 Discovery board. I was able to generate code with the  motor workbench and change and debug it on CUBEIDE.

This week I would like to change the MCU from STM32G431CBU to STM32G431CBT because I prefer the LQFP footprint.

The motor-workbench has no option to for STM32G431CBT so that I stayed with STM32G431CUB because both look like identical. Is that OK?

Today I have soldered my new board with STM32G431CB and debugged it, but it hangs once the Hall sensor pin (TIMER 4 CH 3) is started, because it's shared with BOOT0 Pins PB8. See the enclosed schematic the BOOT0/Hall pin has pull up to 3.3V, not sure if it caused the problem (but on STM32G431CB PB8 / BOOT0 is also pulled up to 3.3V without any issues.)

If I remove the DHALL03 diode and RHALL05 resistor which make PB8 / BOOT0 pin floating (not high), code can run without hanging.

1. Can I use BOOT0 as interrupt (or pull it high)?
2. What makes the STM32G431CBU and STM32G431CBT different? (I have checked on STM32G321CBU's BOOT0 pin as Hall sensor also pull up to 3.3V without any issue)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The BOOT0 pin,by default, is used to go into factory bootloader if it is high when MCU is reset.

So basically, using BOOT0 pin for an input that can be in either state when MCU resets is bad decision.

Fortunately, the G431 default settings can be changed to disable BOOT0 pin to free it as standard GPIO, but then you can't use for entering into factory bootloader any more.

Details how to change the settings is found in MCU documentation, like datasheet, reference manual, factory bootloader appnotes, etc.

Comment: yes, but i have 2 questions : STM32G431CBU which is stock ESC discovery board codes generated by motor workbench has no specific codes to jump its bootloader or set register to disable B8 / boot0 pin, and 2 MUCs are identical ? can you tell me where should i focus on STM32G431CBU codes or files that specify boot0 disable. thanks

Comment: checked both MCU's FLASH register   OPTR = 4226807978, which is nBOOT0 bit = 1 nSWBoot0 bit = 0 and nBoot1 bit = 1 mean boot loader jump to main flash memory and PB8 boot0 pin are disable, can be used for HALL interrupt or pull high at all time, please anyone can help  ?

Comment: update : using STM32CubeProgrammer tool to connect both MCU, I have discovery ST has factory set OPTR register with FBEFF8AA to STM32G431CBU6 because for its discovery board its PB8 use for HALL sensor, and FEEFF8AA to STM32G431CBT which is depend on BOOT0 pin !!! so my next step is to find right tool or code to change this value, many thanks